# jQuery photo grid not having desired effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a photo grid and it's not working out so well. I found this tutorial [here](http://www.gethifi.com/demos/jphotogrid) and i'm trying to replicate the effect. Right now the photos appear and they seem to have some of the `CSS` styles. However when I hover over the photos or click them nothing happens.

**CSS**

```
#pg { 
    position: relative;
    height: 585px; 
    background: #000; 
}

#pg li { 
    position: relative; 
    list-style: none; 
    width: 175px; 
    height: 117px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    float: left; 
    z-index: 2; 
    opacity: .3; 
}

#pg li.active { 
    opacity: 1; 
}

#pg li.selected { 
    opacity: 1; 
    z-index: 99999; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff; 
}

#pg li img { 
    display: block;
    width: 100%; 
}

#pg li p { 
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 0; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}
```

**Javascript file #1**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.jphotogrid = function(settings, callback) {
        settings = $.extend(true, {
            activeClass: 'active',
            selectedClass: 'selected',
            baseCSS: {},
            selectedCSS: {}
        }, settings);

        var url = settings.flickrbase + settings.feedapi + '?';
        var first = true;

        //Convert floats to absolute
        function toAbsolute(el){
            $(el).children().each(function(){
                var pos = $(this).position();
                $(this).data('ptop',Math.floor(Number(pos.top)) + 'px');
                $(this).data('pleft',Math.floor(Number(pos.left)) + 'px');
            }).each(function(){
                placeOriginal(this);
            });
        }

        function placeOriginal(el, animate, callback){
            var dtop = $(el).data('ptop');
            var dleft = $(el).data('pleft');
            var props = $.extend({
                top: dtop,
                left: dleft
            }, settings.baseCSS);
            if(animate){
                $(el).animate(props, 'slow', function(){
                    if($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
                });
            }
            else{
                $(el).css($.extend(props, {position: 'absolute'}));
            }
        }

        function hideSelected(callback){
            $container.find('.' + settings.selectedClass).each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass(settings.selectedClass);
                placeOriginal(this, true);
            });
            if($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
        }

        function select(el){
            hideSelected(function(){
                $(el).addClass('selected').removeClass('active');
                $(el).animate(settings.selectedCSS, 'slow');
            });
        }

        for(var key in settings.qstrings){
            if(!first)
                url += '&';
            url += key + '=' + settings.qstrings[key];
            first = false;
        }

        return $(this).each(function(){
            $container = $(this);
            $(this).css('position','relative');
            toAbsolute(this);

            $(this).children()
                .css('cursor', 'pointer')
                .hover(function(){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass(settings.selectedClass))
                        $(this).addClass(settings.activeClass);
                },function(){
                    $(this).removeClass(settings.activeClass);
                });
            $('.' + settings.activeClass).live('click', function(){             
                select(this);
            });
            $('.' + settings.selectedClass).live('click', function(){
                hideSelected();
            });

            $(this).find('div')
                .hover(function(){
                    $(this).css('opacity', 0);
                },function(){
                    $(this).css('opacity', .5);
                })
                .click(function(){
                    $(this).css('opacity', 0);
                    $li = $(this).parent();
                    $li.css("z-index", 99);
                    $li.animate({
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '400px'
                    }, 'slow');
                });
            });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**Javascript file #2**

```
$('#pg').jphotogrid({
    baseCSS: {
        width: '175px',
        height: '117px',
        padding: '0px'
    },
    selectedCSS: {
        top: '50px',
        left: '100px',
        width: '500px',
        height: '360px',
        padding: '10px'
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['answer_id'])) {
    $answer_id = $_POST['answer_id'];

    $get_pics = $db->prepare('
        SELECT location
        FROM pictures
        WHERE answer_id = ?
    '); 

    $get_pics->bindValue(1, $answer_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $get_pics->execute();

    echo "<ul id='pg'>";

    while ($row = $get_pics->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {     
        echo "<li>" . "<img src='".$row['location']."'/>" . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "<input value='Done' id='cancel_task_pics' type='button' class='form_button' /> ";
}
```

The code looks like it should work. I can't find any errors, so I swapped the position of *where* I included the .js files a few times. That didn't work either. I can include them at the top of the file or the bottom and they still do not seem to be working.

Now I downloaded the zip file from the site and it has some extra css in it. I can't seem to find any relevance for it though. Here it is in case any of you can

**extra CSS**

```
.thumbs li { 
    list-style: none; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 3px; 
    background: #eee; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #444; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; 
}

.thumbs li a { }
.thumbs li img { display: block; }
.thumbs li a img { border: none;}

#cycle { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 333px; 
    padding: 3px; 
    background: #eee; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}

#cycle li { 
    position: relative; 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 3px; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 333px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#cycle li div { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 3px; 
    left: 3px; 
    padding: 3px; 
    width: 494px; 
    background: black; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    opacity: .8; 
}
```

Now this "extra CSS" seems like it should be used, yet I find no mention of it in the tutorial or anywhere in the implementation. I included it in my style.css file anyways but since I'm not calling any of its id's or classes it's obviously not doing much. Anyways this is the most complete amount of information I could gather for this problem. It's kinda driving me nuts. So in summary after that wall of code, the grid is displayed with the pictures inside, however no hover, active, or animation effects are taking place when I hover or click any of the pictures. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? The plugin is built for an older version (1.4) and leverages an API (notably `.live`) that is not present in newer versions of jquery

Comment: @AdamvandenHoven ah, nice catch. I am using 1.10.2, so I guess I should replace `.live` with `.on` right? *edit* I just tried replacing `.live` with `.on` and still no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the demo page (the photo bit) and [made a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/littlefyr/9UaXs/) of the code.

The issue was with the `.live`, as you thought, but just using on was not enough. The code needs to **delegate** the event handling to some ancestor that's not going to go away. The containing element (for which we have a reference already) works well enough.

Here are the changes:

```
        $container.on('click', '.' + settings.activeClass, function(){  
            select(this);
        });
        $container.on('click', '.' + settings.selectedClass, function(){
            hideSelected();
        });
```

Comment: wow man, thank you so much. I know that was not an easy problem to solve and I genuinely appreciate the outstanding fiddle. +1 for being awesome